How can I force using a DNS?
I have multiple network links and I've tried to set the DNS to my Pi-Hole (192.168.1.32), unfortunately resolvectl keeps on filp-flopping between the desired DNS and something else (fe80::1 and goes to my router).
resolvectl status reports
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.32
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.32

Link 2 (enp8s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: fe80::1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.32 fe80::1%23325
        DNS Domain: mynet

Link 3 (wlp6s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

and instead sometimes I get 192.168.1.32 as DNS for my Link 2.
I changed /etc/systemd/resolved.conf adding the DNS=192.168.1.32 entry, but this doesn't seem to have helped, i.e. the Global settings are right, but unfortunately Firefox seems to use the Link 2 settings, hence it doesn't quite work.
How can i force Link 2 to only use my Pi-Hole?
Thanks!

Disable IPv6 on Settings->Network->->IPv6 Tab.

I guess that's the only solution, right? DNS on IPv4 only returns IPv4 records but not IPv6... sorry for the silly remark... for a jiffy I thought the opposite...
